# Как пропускать не весь трафик через клиент openvpn?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, openvpn

Как пропускать не весь трафик через клиент openvpn? Раньше работал на mac где в качестве клиента использовался tunnelblick, пересел на ubuntu 20.04 где использую openvpn. Конфиг для них один и тот же, но работает клиент на ubuntu намного медленнее, корпоративные ресурсы загружает достаточно быстро, но все остальное не загружает почти совсем. Можно ли настроить openvpn, чтоб ходить через него только в определенные ресурсы?

Comment: Ну с маршрутами надо шаманить. `Иф айпи == корпоративный, зэн гото корпоративный гетевей. Элсе гетевей домашнего зухеля`. Или тебе синтаксис нужен?

Comment: решение в ubuntu20.04 такое:  настройки -> сеть -> vpn -> в ipv4/6 ставим галочку "использовать это подключение только для ресурсов этой сети"